# Cross reference to multiple names in the same grammar rule

Tags: eclipse-plugin, grammar, xtext

In my DSL, I have two different rules that can be used to define entities:

First way is by a preset word followed by the name of the entity:

```
Actor Bob

Actor Alice
```

Second way is by creating a relation between two entities:

```
Bob -> Alice
```

Which would be the same as writing

```
Actor Bob -> Actor Alice
```

Now I have a question when it comes to the cross referencing of these entities. Creating a cross reference to the Actors are easy, as I just reference the rule

```
Actor: 
'Actor' name = ID
```

But what happens when I have two ID's in the same rule? How would I go about cross referencing

```
Arrow:
'Actor'? name+=ID '->' 'Actor'? name+=ID
```

Since there are several names in the same rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change how elements are indexed you have to adapt `org.eclipse.xtext.resource.impl.DefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy.createEObjectDescriptions(EObject, IAcceptor<IEObjectDescription>)` and add the elements under all names to the index.

if you want to do this for local definitions as well you have to adapt
`org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.internalGetAllDescriptions(Resource)`

Comment: Would you mind providing some minimal example? I am new to Xtext and I am having some difficulties understanding how you mean that I should adapt these methods. Why would I want to change how elements are indexed?

Comment: i dont know how actors are defined from the reference point of view  (same file or other file) or if you put together the list of visible actors manually). if the do not come from the same file they come from the xtext index. thus you have to adapt the index. if they come from the same file, but you dont collect them manually you have to adapt ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider. if you collect them manually you can simply adapt the scope method.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1696665/?srch=DefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy#msg_1696665

Comment: So I am still not really sure how to Override the apply method in my case. I check `if (from instanceof Arrow)` since my names are in the Arrow rule. I cast `(Arrow) from` and then call `l.getNames()` in the for-loop to add qualified names. I get two errors: `The method transform(Iterable<F>, Function<? super F,? extends T>) in the type Iterables is not applicable for the arguments (Iterable<EObject>, new Function<EObject,List<IEObjectDescription>>(){})` and
`The method create(String, EObject) in the type EObjectDescription is not applicable for the arguments (QualifiedName, EObject)`

Comment: This is my grammar, somewhat minimized: http://pastebin.com/uDwZBtCG

And this is what I am trying to do: Probably very incorrectly)
http://pastebin.com/ksKHJ28i

Comment: your code compiles on my side (com.google.common.base.Function)

Comment: That is very weird. I am still getting errors at both Iterables.transform() and EObjectDescription.create()

Comment: Xtext Complete SDK & Xtext Redistributable version 2.8.3.v201506010551

Comment: that is the same i use